# Multilayer OpenExr Postfixes

Tags: rendering, render-passes, output

When I output my renders to Multilayer OpenExr the layers produced are postfixed by various different strings.

1. What do the postfixes like `.[V]` mean?
2. Where can I find out more info about this from the Blender docs?

**Blender Output Node**

[image: Blendeer Output Node]

**Photoshop Layers**

[image: Photoshop Layers]

Comment: You may want to look at [T71574](https://developer.blender.org/T71574) as a starting point. It will lead you to [Reading and Writing Image Files](https://www.openexr.com/documentation/ReadingAndWritingImageFiles.pdf) that discusses the conventions for naming layers in OpenEXR; but I don't think there is a single place that documents precisely how the layer naming convention is implemented in Blender.

Comment: Interesting. So, the `[V]` is a layer and all three `Matte_*` layers are sub-layers. Any idea what the `[V]` actually stands for? Maybe "View Layer" (but then why isn't `Image.RGBA` called `Image.RGBA.[V]`?)?

Comment: I've been looking at source code and using search engines but I haven't hit on the right search term yet, so no I don't know what the V is.  I'll let you know if anybody gets back to me.